# The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#

Renomeei o nome do projeto e causar diversos problemas no projeto, está dando o erro abaixo. Consegui resolver todos os outros, menos este aqui.

O que pode ser?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você está usando alguma DLL externa? Se sim, qual?

Comment: Faz `grep -r "NomeAntigo" .` (atenção ao ponto no fim) na pasta do projecto para encontrar todas as ocorrencias do antigo nome do projecto. Provavelmente esqueceste-te de actualizar alguma.

Comment: Cigano Morrison, só tem um dll que criei para gerenciamento de abas.. mas esta funcionando perfeitamente.

Comment: Desculpe a ignorância dcastro, mas como realizo este procedimento?